# Pass variables to development.ini on Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, ini

Using Pyramid + MySQL (sqlalchemy), I have the development.ini file and since I'm working with a team, everyone needs different database url on development.ini. Is there anyway to pass variables to development.ini files:

Something like this:

**myconfig.py**

```
DB_USER = 'user'
DB_PASSWORD = 'pass'
DB_DATABASE = 'db_name'
DB_HOSTNAME = 'localhost'
```

**development.ini**

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql://DB_USER:DB_PASSWORD@DB_HOSTNAME/DB_DATABASE
```

That way, every developer can have a non-versioned myconfig.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds kinda complicated - import variables from Python into an `.ini` file only to load that file back into Python :)

How about that:

```
try:
    from .myconfig import DB_STRING
    engine = sa.create_engine(DB_STRING, echo=False)
except ImportError:
    # ... no myconfig.py found - proceed to configuring the engine from .ini file
```